# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: java, shell

I'm getting the below error when trying to run a shell script from java in Eclipse.

I just created a text file on my local and wanted to see if it will run.

```
new ProcessBuilder("C:/Users/myDir/Desktop/ss1.sh").start();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot run a shell script on Windows directly as it is no executable in the Windows sense (only `.exe`, `.com`, `.cmd` and `.bat` are executables).

Call `bash.exe` or `sh.exe` and use your script as the first parameter.

Comment: what does that look like?

Comment: `new ProcessBuilder("path-to-bash/bash.exe C:/Users/myDir/Desktop/ss1.sh").start();` or `new ProcessBuilder("path-to-bash/bash.exe -c C:/Users/myDir/Desktop/ss1.sh").start();`

Comment: thanks that got rid of the error,,,but nothing is happening.  If I run through cygwin directly the script runs

Answer (score -1):

Following MrTux comment I wrapped the py script that I was calling from groovy in a bat file and, voilà!, it works.

Calling directly the py script from groovy

```
def proc = "C:\\MyDir\\myScript.py param1 param2 param3".execute()
proc.waitFor()
def result = proc.in.text
def error = proc.err.text
```

it fails

Wrapping the py script in a bat file
    def proc = "C:\MyDir\myScriptWrapper.bat param1 param2 param3".execute()

works

Wonder why this behaviour in Windows is not better documented. And many thanks to MrTux