# Issue in Compiling SOA 12C project with Maven

Tags: maven, soa, jdeveloper, oracle-soa

I am trying to build my SOA 12.2.1.0.0 project with Maven3.2.5 and using the default Maven local repository.I have done the below steps:
1.Installed the Maven synchronisation plugin to the local respository(mvn install)
2.Pushed all the required libraries to the local repository using Push goal
3.Updated the archetype to reflect the newly installed libraries.

When I am trying to compile the project using Maven, I am getting the below errors like:

> 1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.oracle.adf.library:BC4J-Service-Runtime:pom:12.2.1-0-0'   'No
>   versions available for
>   com.oracle.legacy_oc4j_xml_schemas:com.oracle.webservices.fmw.web-common-schemas-impl:jar:[12.2.1,12.2.2)
>   within specified range

The com.oracle.legacy_oc4j_xml_schemas of the repository contains a folder(com.oracle.webservices.fmw.web-common-schemas-impl) with a single file               `resolver-status.properties` having the content:

```
maven-metadata-central.xml.error=  
maven-metadata-central.xml.lastUpdated=1468297090681
```

**Below is the effective pom:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <groupId>com.oracle.soa</groupId>
    <artifactId>sar-common</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.1-0-0</version>
    <relativePath></relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>MavenIntegrationApplication</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestProjectMaven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>sar</packaging>
    <description>Oracle FMW Common Parent POM</description>
    <url>http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/overview/index.html/sar-common/TestProjectMaven</url>
    <inceptionYear>2012</inceptionYear>
    <properties>
    <password></password>
    <scac.input>D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven/SOA//composite.xml</scac.input>
    <oraclePassword></oraclePassword>
    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
    <composite.partition>default</composite.partition>
    <regenerateRulebase>false</regenerateRulebase>
    <scac.error>D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven/target/error.txt</scac.error>
    <oracleServerUrl>http://localhost:7003</oracleServerUrl>
    <scac.output.dir>D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven/target</scac.output.dir>
    <composite.revision>1.0</composite.revision>
    <oracleHome>${env.ORACLE_HOME}</oracleHome>
    <forceDefault>true</forceDefault>
    <scac.displayLevel>1</scac.displayLevel>
    <composite.name>TestProjectMaven</composite.name>
    <input>TestProjectMaven</input>
    <keepInstancesOnRedeploy>false</keepInstancesOnRedeploy>
    <scac.output>D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven/target/out.xml</scac.output>
    <scac.input.dir>D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven/SOA/</scac.input.dir>
    <oracleServerName>soa_server1</oracleServerName>
    <oracleUsername></oracleUsername>
    <serverUrl>http://localhost:7003</serverUrl>
    <scatest.result>D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven/target/testResult</scatest.result>
    <oracleMiddlewareHome>/home/myhome/Oracle/Middleware</oracleMiddlewareHome>
    <user></user>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>SOA-Designtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.2.1-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>SOA-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.2.1-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>BPEL-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.2.1-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>Mediator-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.2.1-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>MDS-Runtime</artifactId>
      <version>12.2.1-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven\target</directory>
    <finalName>TestProjectMaven-1.0-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.oracle.soa.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>oracle-soa-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.1-0-0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <compositeName>TestProjectMaven</compositeName>
          <composite>D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven/SOA//composite.xml</composite>
          <sarLocation>D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven/target/sca_TestProjectMaven_rev1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</sarLocation>
          <serverUrl>http://localhost:7003</serverUrl>
          <user></user>
          <password></password>
          <compositeRevision>1.0</compositeRevision>
          <revision>1.0</revision>
          <scacInputDir>D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven/SOA/</scacInputDir>
          <input>TestProjectMaven</input>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.oracle.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>oracle-maven-sync</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.1-0-0</version>
        <configuration>
          <serverId>internal</serverId>
          <oracleHome>D:\OracleSOA12C\Oracle_Home</oracleHome>
          <testOnly>false</testOnly>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdeploy</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.1-0-0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <ojdeploy>${env.ORACLE_HOME}/jdeveloper/jdev/bin/ojdeploy.exe</ojdeploy>
          <workspace>D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven/../MavenIntegrationApplication.jws</workspace>
          <project>TestProjectMaven</project>
          <profile>TestProjectMaven</profile>
          <outputfile>D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven\target/TestProjectMaven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</outputfile>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Can someone help me solve this issue, if I have missed to do some steps.

Comment: It seems Maven can't resolve this dependency. Can you share your pom.xml ?

Comment: Mickael, Updated the dependencies in the POM in above original query post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved.It was because not all dependent jars were getting installed using the PUSH command(reason is unknown).After few more trials(deleting and reexceuting the commands), all the jars got installed and now the all the goals are hetting executed successfuly.
Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove `<type>pom</type>` of your dependencies.

If I understand your problem correctly, you have Oracle libs (most likely JARs) provided somewhere so you don't want Maven to include these libs in your packaging. But as you indicate `<type>pom</type>`, Maven is trying to get the POM of these dependecies and it's not working.

Comment: Yes That's correct.I have pushed the Oracle libraries to the Maven repository(local).Now I have removed the unwanted dependencies and now when the project is compiled error thrown is 'org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.oracle.soa.plugin:oracle-soa-plugin:12.2.1-0-0:compile (default-compile) on project TestProjectMaven: SOA COMPILE failed with value: Cannot run program "C:\JDK\jdk8\bin\java" (in directory "D:\JDEVWorkspace-12C\TestProjectMaven"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application',

Comment: Can you please provide your entire `pom.xml` ?

Comment: Updated in original query.This is the default POM that got generated and I haven't done any customization.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25511402/java-io-ioexception-cannot-run-program-createprocess-error-193-1-is-not-a, you probably have a problem with your JDK. Can you run the command `C:\JDK\jdk8\bin\java -version` ?

Comment: C:\JDK\jdk8\bin\java -version gives                                                             '   `java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b15, mixed mode)`

Comment: And I am running it on windows 7 64 bit machine and also set the JAVA_HOME and PATH variables.